# Have the trilogy sites lost traffic and usage due to Stack Exchange sites or in general?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I've noticed a decline in responses on Super User over the past few weeks/months. I'll admit that I don't necessarily follow it all that well in the first place, but it seems as though questions asked there can fall into a black hole vs. Stack Overflow.

Has there been a decline in traffic to Super User? What about the rest of the [trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) sites?

If traffic is being lost, is it possible that the Stack Exchange sites are cutting into trilogy traffic and spreading the audiences too thin to make sustainable communities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are seeing a slight, minor decline in traffic to SU and SF -- but overall traffic for the entire network including SO and [all SE 2.0 sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is way, way up.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem may be that super user has a **very** broad audience, so it suffers more from other area51 websites "stealing" questions.

Stack Overflow has a broad audience too but:

- Definitely not as broad as Super User
- Stack Overflow also has much better reputation. If I post a question on SO I know I almost have the guarantee that I will get an answer within 5 minutes, so I don't even think about asking it on another website.

  On SU, from my - somewhat limited - experience I noticed I may not get an answer, so I'm open to try a more specific website.

Comment: Unix, Ubuntu and Apple proposal are indeed overlapping with Super User. These proposal might take most of the Mac & Linux user from Super User.

Comment: In terms of subject matter, the entire programming world and the entire non-server computing world are equally broad subjects

Comment: I hope that Super User dies a horrible death. And by that, I mean becomes refocused to actually be of use to people. :\

Answer (score -1):

I have always found that Super User is very hit and miss when I ask a question.  But SO still seem to give good answers.